# Reverse Engineer to get UML with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, uml, reverse-engineering

Are there are any tools available for use with Postgres so that I can generate UML for the database that I have already created.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Paradigm has some nice products, check http://www.visual-paradigm.com/ Most of their products work on Linux, OS X and Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt this script for MySQL
http://askuml.com/blog/list-all-fields-of-all-mysql-db-tables-in-yuml-class-diagrams/
by just changing the driver from Mysql to Postgress found here http://softinnov.org/rebol/pgsql.shtml

This is a sample reverse enginiering for Wordpress DB:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

ppstgres_autodoc is the standard open source tool. http://www.rbt.ca/autodoc/

Answer (score 0):

I have used [SQL Power Architect](http://www.sqlpower.ca/page/architect) which has a free version to do most of the tasks you need with reverse engineering and stuff like that. I found it to be easy to use and simple.